# Is there a way to read programming languages on an iphone?

Tags: java, php, iphone, c++, ruby-on-rails

Something like github on an iphone for times I'm not at the desk would come in handy..

Is there such thing?

Comment: In what way do you mean "read"? What does textmate do?

Comment: They're just text files. Are you looking for syntax highlighting, context-aware editing or what?

Comment: I'm learning a new programming language and sometimes I just like to read through code whether it's mine or some one elses.. I normally use github for this but at times I take a break from the desk or when I go to bed I like to spend a few hours browsing on my iphone. An app that would allow me to read code would be great. Kind of like github on my phone.

Comment: No syntax highlighting needed. Just need to be able to easily access for example a frameworks folder with all the files present.

Comment: You could try porting Eclipse ;-)

Comment: This was a trigger happy closing! FAQ: "We feel the best Stack Overflow questions have a bit of source code in them, but if your question generally covers...
software tools commonly used by programmers ... then you’re in the right place to ask your question!"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a handfull of IDE Apps available for Ios: A simple search for *"Iphone IDE App"* yealded:

[Gusto - Code Editor and FTP Client](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/gusto-code-editor-ftp-client/id364906873?mt=8)

[Markup for iPad](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/markup-for-ipad/id365590383?mt=8)

[Mides IDE](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/mides-ide/id284965983?mt=8)

[Source Viewer XL](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/source-viewer-xl/id364691406?mt=8)